# com.mysql.cj.exceptions.DataConversionException: Cannot determine value type from string ' '

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am getting the following error when I try to get more than 100 records from mysql using Spring-Boot.
However, if the database has only 99 records then the code works fine.....

My Code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
        List<ServicesDetails> Serviceslist = entityManager.createQuery(
                "select r from ServiceAttributeMapping r INNER JOIN r.serviceAttribute i where r.mapWith=:mapWith and r.fLikedWithMainService='Y' and r.status='1' ")
                .setParameter("mapWith", "MAIN").getResultList();
        return Serviceslist;
```

Error :

```
2019-09-26 09:36:51.131  WARN 6476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22018
2019-09-26 09:36:51.131 ERROR 6476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot determine value type from string ' '

com.mysql.cj.exceptions.DataConversionException: Cannot determine value type from string ' '
    at com.mysql.cj.result.AbstractNumericValueFactory.createFromBytes(AbstractNumericValueFactory.java:66) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeByteArray(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:133) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.TextBufferRow.getValue(TextBufferRow.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
```

If I print the response on console.log one web page then it shows:

```
error:  "Internal Server Error"
exception: "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException"
```

Comment: what are the data types on your table. I had similar issue with some boolean fields (Reference : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92574). We had to fix some data to work around

Comment: set the show-sql true and see the query generate by hibernate and execute same from mysql client and see if something is wrong with data, in most case you may find that some column is blank or something

Comment: query work fine , but if there less then 100 records , if more then 100 records in database then its though error

Comment: Looks like you have the record number 100 with an empty column value ` ` then make sure that you have the record number 100 with the column values as 99 have.